# Cannot read property 'startRecorder' of undefined error when starting audio recording in react native app using expo

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to record audio using an expo react native application.
I declare in one of my function component `App` the constant `audioRecorderPlayer`. When I try to access it in the function `onStartRecord` I get the error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'startRecorder'
> of undefined

pointing to the line with `audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder()` inside `onStartRecord`.

How do I have to implement `audioRecorderPlayer` in Typescript or ES6 to be able to access it in the `onStartRecord` method and all my functions within the `App` component?

I added my code on [snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/W2HJ6lMQ3) like suggested.
The code is resulting in the same undefined error when clicking the start record button as when runnig it locally.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'startRecorder'
> of undefined

Here is some modified `react` code which seems to work.
The original code above on snack.expo is not working.

```js
class AudioRecorderPlayer {
  startRecorder(): Promise < string > {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve('Success!');
    });
  }
}

interface Props {
  audioRecorderPlayer: AudioRecorderPlayer;
}

const App: React.FC < Props > = (props) => {
  // This is where I initialize the constant
  const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();

  const onStartRecord = () => {
    // Here I try to access it
    console.log('Button clicked!')
    audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder()
      .then((result: string) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  };


  return ( 
    <div>
      <p> Press Button to trigger function </p> 
      <button onClick = {() => onStartRecord()}>
        Start Recording 
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  App title = "My App" / > ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Try instead storing `audioRecorderPlayer` in state using `useState` or `useRef` or similar.

Comment: I'm afraid the code in the question is too fragmentary for us to be able to help you with it. If you really had that declaration and initialization of `audioRecorderPlayer` where it is (at the top level of the component function), you would be able to access it everywhere in that function -- and it would be getting created far too often, most likely, as component functions get called repeatedly to update the component. (As Alexander says, you'd want to hold it in state or in a ref.) ...

Comment: ... Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (Naturally this will involve using a stand-in for the audio recorder class, etc.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added  a minimal reproducible example with some minor modifications, which is running. The original Code fails never the less...

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I tried to use `useState` without success

Comment: Both of your versions work for me with that `AudioRecorderPlayer` class.  Perhaps the issue is the previous version was from the `AudioRecorderPlayer` rather than the `App` component.  Can you create an Expo Snack that reproduces the issue? https://snack.expo.io/  I recommend that you take @Alexander's suggestion and use `useRef`. `const audioRecorderPlayer = useRef(new AudioRecorderPlayer()).current;`

Comment: @LindaPaiste  Thank you for the information. I have uploaded my code to snack.expo to reproduce the issue. The same error occurs there as with me locally. And this although I use `useRef`.

Answer (score 0):

Without ejecting, not every library is useable in expo with the managed workflow.

For the managed workflow, [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/audio/) is the recommended audio recorder library.

The expo client won't allow incompatible libraries such as the one you [used](https://reactnative.directory/?search=react-native-audio-recorder-player) in the snack you shared unless you eject.

[This](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/#determining-third-party-library-compatibility) goes into more detail.

[expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/audio/) is the way to go for the managed workflow. Snacks are always managed so the demo won't work without changing libraries.
Libraries that contain native code (ios and/or android folders) that aren't listed as supporting expo in [React Native Directory](https://reactnative.directory/) won't work in the managed workflow.